# PHP echo does not display JSON from server

Tags: php, mysql, json

The connection to the database is successful (it's on a server, not local), the query works fine (I echo the name, street works fine), BUT it never echoes the json string back to me.

I tried several tutorials from Google how to convert mysql to json but I never get a result out of it. No errors either.

```
<?php
    include "dbconnect.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Test ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $json_array = array();  

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {  
          $json_array[] = $row;  
          echo "<br>";
          echo $row["name"];
          echo $row["street"];
          echo $row["farbe"];
     }  
    
     echo json_encode($json_array);  
 ?>
```

Comment: Go read the manual for json_encode, please. It should contain all the information you need.

Comment: Can you please paste full table info?

Comment: `print_r($json_array);` what you get???

Comment: i get   ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Testi [street] => Teststra�e 1 [farbe] => Blau ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Tomas [street] => Teststra�e 2 [farbe] => gr�n ) ). finally a result but i just wanted to output a plain json like [{name: john, age: 12}] for example